# Как найти значение периодической функции?

Tags: c++, c

Помогите пожалуйста решить задачу, проблема в том, что данное решение является ошибочным, и в данном коде нужно исправить ошибку, что бы выдаваемые значения совпадали с графиком, долго уже мучаюсь но решения так и не нашёл.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
#include <iostream>

#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
int main(void) {
 short n;        /* параметр внешнего цикла */
 double x, y;    /* абсцисса и ордината графика */
 short h;        /* позиция точки на экране */
    /* внешний цикл - для 5 периодов */
    for (n=0; n<5; n++) {
      /* вывод заголовка таблицы */
      printf("|   x   |      y     |\n");
      printf("|-------|------------|\n");
      /* внутренний цикл для одного периода */
      for (x = 0; x < 4; x += 0.25) {
        /* 1-й отрезок */
        if (x < 1) y = 2 * x - 1;
        /* 2-й отрезок */
        else if (x < 3) y = 1 - sqrt(1-(x-2) * (x-2));
        /* 3-й отрезок */
        else y = 7-2 * x;
        /* вывод строки таблицы */
        printf("| %5.2lf | %10.7lf |",x+n * 4,y);
        /* определение позиции точки */
        h=(y+1) * 10;
        if (y-1-h * 10>0.5) h++;
        /* вывод точки графика */
        for (; h>0; h--) printf(" ");
        printf("\n");
        }  /* конец внутреннего цикла */
      /* пауза до команды оператора */
      printf("Нажмите клавишу Enter...");
      getchar();
      }  /* конец внешнего цикла */
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Первый отрезок с ошибкой.

Comment: Третий отрезок с ошибкой.

Comment: Второй отрезок - не отрезок совсем. Вы знаете что такое линейная  интерполяция?

Comment: В графике функции не может быть вертикальных участков, если это график функции а не произвольная ломанная.

Comment: Чему равно Y при X == 2?

Comment: Это похоже осциллограмма какая-то. X=2 Y=2, X=2.1 Y=1 - наверно так, если это осциллограмма (это для примера)

Comment: @Виктор Нет уж, при X = 2.1 по графику Y = 0.8...

Comment: @Harry я же написал: это для примера :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну, раз уж вы трудились, можно и помочь :)
Примерно так (для x >= 0, для отрицательных `fmod()` дает отрицательные значения — как с ними справиться, "оставим читателю в качестве упражнения" :))

```
double Y(double x)
{
    x = fmod(x,4);
    if (x < 2) return (3*x-2)/2;
    else if (x == 2) return // Так чему равно Y при x == 2?
    else if (x < 3) return 5 - 2*x;
    else return -1;
}
```

Соответственно, в таблицу писать, не мудрствуя лукаво, тем более что у вас нет 5 *полных* периодов:

```
for(double x = 0; x <= 19; x += 0.25)
    printf("| %5.2lf | %10.7lf |\n",x,Y(x));
```